# assigning an operator to a variable in xquery

Tags: xquery

is there a way to assign a numeric operator to a variable in Xquery?

I have to perform an arithmetic expression on a given pair of values depending upon a node tag.

I've managed to do this but its resulted in a lot of duplicate code.  I'd like to simplify the query so that instead of:

*Function for Add*

*Repeated if code - this calls out to other functions but is still repeated*

$value1 + $value2

*Function for Minus*

*Repeated if code*

$value1 - $value2

*etc for multiply, div etc*

I'd like to set up a function and send a variable to it, something similar to this:

$value1 $operator $value2

Is there a simple way to do this in xquery?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query processor supports [*XQuery 3.0*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/), you can use [*function items*](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_3.0#Function_Items) for that:

```
declare function local:foo($operator, $x, $y) {
  let $result := $operator($x, $y)
  return 2 * $result
};
```

`local:foo(...)` can then be called like this:

```
let $plus := function($a, $b) { $a + $b },
    $mult := function($a, $b) { $a * $b }
return (
  local:foo($plus, 1, 2),
  local:foo($mult, 3, 4)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a simple if-else construct? E.g.

```
if (repeated code says you should add) then
  $value1 + $value2
else
  $value1 - $value2
```

You could also simple put the *repeated code* in another function instead of copying the code.

Comment: ah sorry, my mistake for trying to simplify the question above. There are a few more operators than described and a few repetitions of the expression.